# React component constructor (Parsing error: Unexpected token , expected "}")

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

> Parsing error: unexpected token, expected `}`

on the `{` of `constrctor(props){`

I have some other class above this one doing the same thing as `constructor(props)` but no error

if I add `}` before this class, no matter how many `}` I added, the error is the same.

if I add `{` before this class, and `}` after it, it is ok, but the class below this one would show the same error on constructor

After I tried to add `{}` too surround each class below, it would show

> Parsing Error: unterminated JSX contents

right before `export`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
    import './App.css';
    import $ from 'jquery';

//some classes extends React.Component

class CommentRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.DeleteComment=this.DeleteComment.bind(this);
  }

  DeleteComment(e) {
    this.props.dComment(e.target._id);
  }

  render() {
    const comment=this.props.comment
    if (comment.name==this.state.name)
        var yourcomment=<tr _id={comment._id} ondoubleclick={this.DeleteComment}> 
        else 
        var yourcomment=<tr _id={comment._id}>
    return (
    {yourcomment}
    <td>comment.time</td>
    <td>comment.name</td>
    <td><p> said: </p></td>
    <td id="comentcontent">comment.content</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            ....
            some functions
        }
    render(){
        return(
            //some more code
        );
    }
}



class FrontApp extends React.Component {
    //constructor
    render(){
        return(
            //some more code
            <Profile
                  //some function
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Frontapp
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, can you post a remaining snippet also

Comment: `Class` should not have a capital `c`. Is this your error? Should be `class Profile...`

Comment: just a typo, i used small letter c

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine then. I think there is another error in something you haven't posted. Might need the rest of the class to spot it.

Comment: the code has 600+ lines... It's hard to post them all

Comment: well best bet is for you to recreate the class chunk by chunk through copy pasting  it until you find the part of the code causing the error. it's likely some code that has an extra (or is missing a) bracket or character of some kind. we can't really help with that without your actual code

Comment: do you have alias for $ in your bable? if not change it to import { $ } from 'jquery';

Comment: just tried and notice that the problem is most probably at the commentrow class

Comment: there are some functions use $.ajax of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that way of returning something in your `CommentRow`'s render function is valid, even though technically the variable `yourcomment` is the opening `<tr>` tag it's needing. (You also had a few other small syntax errors in your JSX).

Instead try to have the `<tr>` there and conditional add props to it, like so:

```
render() {
    const { comment } = this.props;
    const { name } = this.state;

    return (
    <tr _id={comment._id} onDoubleClick={comment.name === name && this.DeleteComment}>
       <td>{comment.time}</td>
       <td>{comment.name}</td>
       <td><p> said: </p></td>
       <td id="comentcontent">{comment.content}</td>
    </tr>
    );
  }
```